# All networks are hidden for me

Tags: 12.04, wireless, macbook

I've been setting up my Ubuntu (on a Macbook Pro, 64 bit), and I've run into a bit of a snag with wireless.

The first time I started up Ubuntu, the first thing I did was connect to my router via ethernet and run the following commands to install the drivers for my wireless card. These commands are

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mpodroid/mactel
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

I then ran added the line

```
blacklist ndiswrapper
```

to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

and then created the file /etc/pm/config.d/modules, editing it to include

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="b43 bcma"
```

I then rebooted. I've actually installed Ubuntu on this very computer five or six times now, so this is almost standard procedure for me.

Anyways, I clicked on the wireless pop-up in the top-right corner. None of the networks showed up. Suspicious, I clicked "connect to a hidden network," entered my network's name and password, and what do you know? I was able to connect to my home network. The other local networks also showed up in the drop-down menu.

When I restarted later however, none of the networks showed up. I went to "connect to a hidden network" again, chose the right profile, and I was able to connect. Again, the other local networks showed up.

I figured that it was just a temporary problem- I set the settings to autoconnect to my home network. When I rebooted the next time however the same problem occurred, even though the "connect on startup" box in the home network was still checked.

The network can't be hidden, as I can connect to it using Windows 8, Windows 7, Mac OSX, and they've all recognized it without me having to manually input the network name.

I'm baffled here. Any help?

Comment: Baffling indeed. FTR, there are a number of duplicate questions (such as [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/123369/no-wifi-networks-show-up-in-list?rq=1), [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/204088/my-wireless-network-is-not-listed-hidden-network?rq=1) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/355522/ubuntu-12-04-thinks-my-wireless-network-is-hidden-but-its-not?rq=1)), but none have an accepted answer. Have you tried installing without the mactel PPA? MBP models differ a lot, but raring and saucy work fine on my 6,2 with just the default repo's and settings.

Comment: What is your wireless device from the command: lspci -nn -d 14e4:

Comment: Here's the output `02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4] (rev 10)
02:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Corporation BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 10)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
`